# Is it possible to use an ACTION_SENTO Intent to send to multiple recipients?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want my app to share data with multiple people. Ideally I'd like for the user to be able to select a contact group, and it would launch an intent to share that data with everyone in the contact group, e.g. Open Gmail with the address field populated with that group of users' email addresses. Is this possible using an `ACTION_SENDTO` Intent? I can't even find an example of how to use it to send to one person, let alone multiple yet.

Answer (score 4):

Using `ACTION_SEND` and `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` will not limit the app chooser to email apps only. Instead, use `ACTION_SENDTO`, as in:

```
final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);

emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:first.mail@gmail.com,second.mail@gmail.com"));

emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "your subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "email content");

startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

As seen in the example, you can send an email to multiple recipients by comma-separating the Uri. There is no need to catch `ActivityNotFoundException` from `startActivity(..)`, as the android framework will handle it for you an show an appropriate message to the user.

If you want the format the email in html, you can use:

```
emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<i>my html-formatted text!</i>"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have used the following statement in your code

`emailIntent .putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"user@example.com"});`

it accepts String array, you can pass multiple recipient name over there

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` as an action for email launching intent for sending data to multiple recipients.

create a list of email ids and use it against `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` key, as this will include all emails from email-list in *to* field of send email form.

How about this code:

```
final Intent emailLauncher = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
emailLauncher.setType("message/rfc822");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailList);
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "check this subject line");
emailLauncher.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "hey check this message body!");
try{
       startActivity(emailLauncher);
}catch(ActivityNotFoundException e){
      
}
```

Comment: ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE is to deliver multiple DATA to someone else.